# Why is there a java.exe in the Java JDK folder?

Tags: java

`java.exe` is for running the class file. As per my understanding, it's not used for compiling Java code. Then what is the use of `java.exe` at this location on my system: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\java.exe`

Comment: I guess it would be handy to be able to run what you have compiled.

Comment: AFAIK, It's so you can include one directory in your path to get everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, it's to run the compiled Java code. And it's there so that you can use easily include it in a CLASS-PATH variable(in Windows it'll help you run java from command line ).

```
java myNewProg
```

The JDK subsumes the JRE - i.e if you get the JDK you'lll also get all the JRE stuff. But if you download only JRE, you won't have everything

Comment: Heh, OP answers his own question in the first line of the question. :)

Comment: I think his point is, why is it in the JDK folder when there's on in the JRE?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - OK yes, I see.. OK I will edit

Comment: you are correct  Ash Burlaczenko. and @Adel, if we can run the compiled java code using java.exe presence in jdk folder,, then why we need jre folder..

Comment: @user840477: I think you mean the opposite, whys is it in the jdk folder, if you can find it in the jre folder? :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, while i downloaded and installing java, it installed jdk and jre, by this i thought that, jdk folder is only for developing purpose and jre is for running, now i understood thing that   jdk kit is for developing and alos testing program..

Answer (score 1):

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre` is the location of the runtime environment; you can use it to redistribute with your applications, and therefore contains `java` to be able to run it;
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0` is the location of the development environment.  It contains in its `bin` folder both `javac` (to compile your code) and `java` (to run your code) -- arguably you may want to run the code you are developing.  That `java` executable is indeed the same as the one in the `jre`.

Answer (score 0):

JDK stands for Java DEVELOPER Kit, so it includes all the tools to compile and TEST your programs, like you said in the first line.